# UIBezier Path Refusing to Draw

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

I'm trying to draw a arch using `UIBezierPath`. There are no errors or warnings and I cannot see any obvious bugs but it just will not draw. This is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    

CGFloat a = 10;

CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);

CGPoint center = CGPointMake(width/2, height/2);
CGFloat radius = MAX(width, height);
CGFloat archWidth = 18;
CGFloat archLengthPerA = 5;
CGFloat startAngle = 3 * M_PI /2;
CGFloat endAngle = archLengthPerA * a + startAngle;

UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path addArcWithCenter:center
                      radius:radius
                  startAngle:startAngle
                    endAngle:endAngle
                   clockwise:YES];

path.lineWidth = archWidth;
[[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:17 blue:0 alpha:1.0] setStroke];
[path stroke];
}
```

I put it in a separate view to test and it crashed on `_myString` so is that anything to do with it? I tried adding a breakpoint to see if it worked without it but then it crashed again. Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Step through it with the debugger and see what values `_myString` and `a` and `startAngle` and `endAngle` have. Most likely `a` is 0, thus `startAngle` is the same as `endAngle`, thus you are asking for an arc with zero size, which of course draws nothing. You could easily change your code to check what happens when `a` is different values -- for instance, `CGFloat a = 1.0;`.

Comment: @KurtRevis just checked and they have values so its not that

Comment: So _what values do they have_? Give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value of `radius` is too large, so the arc is drawn outside of the view.

Make it smaller. For instance:

```
CGFloat radius = MIN(width/2, height/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, your colour values are incorrect:

[[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:17 blue:0 alpha:1.0] setStroke];

The colour components of that class method should be CGFloat with values between 0.0 and 1.0